# Laplace transform of $\sqrt[3]{t}$ using Gamma function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, gamma-function

Can I ask what is the Laplace transform of $\sqrt[3]{t}$ using the Gamma function?
This was my initial answer. Note that there is a theorem, $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})=3\Gamma(\frac{4}{3})$. $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\exp^{-\beta} \beta^{-\frac{2}{3}}=3\int^{\infty}_{0}\exp^{-\beta} \beta^{\frac{4}{3}}$$ And was able to get the final answer of $$\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})=9\exp^{-\beta} \beta^{\frac{4}{3}}|^{\infty}_{0}+12\exp^{-\beta} \beta^{\frac{1}{3}}|^{\infty}_{0}$$
I don't know then whats the next thing to do.

Comment: $\dfrac{\Gamma \left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)}{s^{4/3}}$, see Item $4$: in the [*Laplace table*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).

Comment: the corresponding laplace integral is nearly the defintion of the gamma function. you should be able to figure this out by yourself

Comment: i've tried to answer it using the relationship, Gamma(1/3)=3Gamma(4/3) and i'm able to get the answer Gamma(1/3)=9e^-B B^4/3 (evaluated from  to infinity) plus 12e^-B B^1/3 (evaluated from 0 to infinity). what to do with this? thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: Though its difficult to understand but still thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Laplace of $t^n$ is $[\Gamma (n+1)]/[s^{(n+1)}]$

So if we put $n=1/2$, we get $\Gamma (1/2) ÷ (s^{1/2})$ and $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Hence the answer is $\sqrt{\pi/s}$. Hope this will help  calculating the Laplace of $t^n$.

Comment: t^n, n=1/2 is easy to solve its laplace transform but please try solving it using n=1/3 because i'm stuck in the part where the final answer is evaluated from 0 to infinity. thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! You can start learning about how to write equations using mathjax here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: this is my final answer by the way: 9\exp^{-\beta}\beta^{\frac{4}{3}}|^{\infty}_{0}+12\exp^{-\beta}\beta^{\frac{1}{3}}|^{\infty}_{0}

Answer (score 0):

The Gamma function can be defined as

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty\text{d}x\,e^{-x}x^{z-1}$$

The Laplace transform you want to compute is

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{t^{1/3}\right\}=\int_0^\infty\text{d}t\,e^{-ts}t^{1/3}$$

Performing the change of variables $ts=y$ you have

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{L}\left\{t^{1/3}\right\}&=\int_0^\infty s^{-1}\text{d}y\,e^{-y}y^{1/3}s^{-1/3}\\&=s^{-4/3}\int_0^\infty \text{d}y\,e^{-y}y^{\frac{4}{3}-1}\\
&=s^{-4/3}\Gamma(4/3)\end{align}$$

Comment: you need some complex analysis here, $s$ is complex and your change of variable doesn't work then

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio with $y = st$ the correct result is $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-st} dt = s^{-a}\int_0^{\,s\,\infty}y^{a-1} e^{-y}dy$ quite different (at first) to $s^{-a} \Gamma(a)$

Comment: @user1952009: all right, but it is straightforward to prove that $$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\int_{s N}^{N}y^{a-1}e^{-y}\,dy = 0 $$ by the ML lemma, hence the previous integral equals $s^{-a}\Gamma(a)$ as expected.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio for this you need to say that $g(y) = y^{a-1} e^{-y}$ has an holomorphic antiderivative (or use the Cauchy integral theorem) so that $\int_A^B g(y)dy$ doesn't depend on the path $A \to B$, and it becomes more complicated than my proof above

Comment: @user1952009: but $y^{a-1}e^{-y}$ is clearly holomorphic in the right half-plane. Anyway, I am taking a step back, this approach probably requires a tiny bit of complex analysis.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I already answered ~10 times to this same question, and I tried all the possible proofs. The one I chose for people not knowing complex analysis is the one I wrote. Note that the case $s= i, Re(a) \in (0,1)$ is a little bit more difficult, and in that case I prefer what you wrote

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio and I upvoted you 2 times yesterday ;) (and the day before and...)

Comment: @user1952009: thank you :). I took back my previous *I do not agree*.

Answer (score 0):

The correct proof needs some complex analysis.

Define for $Re(s) > 0$ : $$\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$

Then for real $s \in (0,\infty)$ you have 
$$\mathcal{L}[t^{1/3}1_{ t > 0}](s) = \int_0^\infty t^{1/3} e^{-st} dt \underset{x \ = \ st}= s^{-4/3}\int_0^\infty x^{1/3} e^{-x} dx = s^{-4/3}\Gamma(4/3)$$

Now note that both the LHS and the RHS are complex analytic for $Re(s) > 0$, and since they are equal for $s \in (0,\infty)$, by the [identity theorem for complex analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)  (or if you prefer by [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)) it proves they are equal for every $Re(s) > 0$.

(the idea of the identity theorem is that if a function $h(s)$ is complex analytic and non identically zero, then its zeros are isolated, but here $\mathcal{L}[t^{1/3}1_{ t > 0}](s)-s^{-4/3}\Gamma(4/3)$ is complex analytic on $Re(s) > 0$ and identically zero on the real line, hence it is identically zero on $Re(s) > 0$)

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[t^{\frac{1}{\text{n}}}\right]_{\text{s}}=\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{1}{\text{n}}}\cdot e^{-\text{s}t}\space\text{d}t=\text{s}^{-\frac{1+\text{n}}{\text{n}}}\Gamma\left\{1+\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right\}$$

When $\Re\left[\text{s}\right]>0\space\wedge\space\Re\left[\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right]>-1$